# Java Access The Object That Instantiated

Tags: java, oop, instantiation

I don't know how to access the class that instantiated an object from that object.

Example for clarity:

```
public class A {

    B b;
    int number = 5;

    public A() {
        b = new B();
    }
}

public class B {

    public B() {
        System.out.println(/*code to get the value of number*/);
    }
}
```

And I can't just pass `number` into `B`

Is this even possible in java?

Comment: You'd need to have a field in `B` that stores its creator, a constructor that sets it, and the word `this` inside the parentheses when you create the object.

Comment: You could use nested classes. If you make class B nested to class A, then class B will have access to even private fields of class A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects don't inherently know where they were instantiated, no.

That said, you can add a reference to the instantiating object in to the sub object. This can be useful in board implementations, so tiles or spaces can have a reference to the board object for neighbors, etc.

For your example, if all `B`s are instantiated by a corresponding `A`, you could modify the classes as such:

```
public class A {

    B b;
    int number = 5;

    public A() {
        b = new B(this);
    }
}

public class B {

    public final A instant;

    public B(A a) {
        instant = a;
        System.out.println(a.number);
    }
}
```

Another way to achieve the same affect, if all Bs are constructed within an a `A` is to make `B` a *non-static inner class*. This will give each `B` access to the number field of its corresponding `A`.

```
public class A {
    B b;
    int number = 5;

    public A() {
        b = new B(this);
    }

    class B {
        public B() {
            System.out.println(number); //Has access because it must be constructed within an A instance
        }
    }
}
```

This is clearly cleaner, but making `B` an inner class has other design implications that may or may not be appropriate for your project.

If you don't know the class of the instantiating object (if it's not always `A`), however, then neither of these approaches will work. In that case the best you can do is either make the argument to constructing `B` of type `Object` and cast as necessary to get at fields, or make it some interface shared by the instantiating classes with shared behavior as necessary. Here's an example of that:

```
public interface Instantiator{
    public int getNumber();
}

public class A1 implements Instantiator{
    private B b;
    public A() {
        b = new B(this);
    }

    public int getNumber(){
        return 5;
    }
}

public class C implements Instantiator{
    private B b;
    private int count = 0;

    public C(){
        count++;
        b = new B(this);
    }

    public int getNumber(){
        return count;
    }
}

public class B {

    public final Instantiator instant;

    public B(Instantiator a) {
        instant = a;
        System.out.println(a.getNumber());
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice that the variable held in `B` does not update along with the variable held in `A`, is there any better/proper way to fix this other than an `Update()` method? Like in haleys answer. Also, thanks for the great answer.

Comment: While that behavior could be added, I don't think it would actually do anything. Whenever you "update" the `b` field of an `A` object, you're constructing a *new* `B` object, who will of course have an up to date `a` field.

Comment: I was thinking for a game loop, but it is trivial anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In Object Orientation language like Java first you need to provide encapsulation that is basically put all the atributes private and then use set to pass the value for example and also if you want to access number you can inhereate from A usend keyword **extend** also you can put the atribute number in class B and then you can do something like a.getB().setNumber() or getNumber() depends what you want getter is for read the value and setter is for set the value:

```
public class A {

  B b;
  private int number;

        public A() {
                b = new B();
        }

        public void setNumber(int number){
    this.number=number;
        }

        public int getNumber(){
            return number;
        }
}
```

then in the class B

```
public class B extends A {

    public class B(){
        setNumber(100);
    }

}
```

Comment: I know about extends, but it is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A {

    B b;
    int number = 5;

    public A() {
        b = new B();
        b.setNum(number);
    }
}

public class B {
    int number;
    public B() {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
    public void setNum(int n) {
        number = n;
    }
}
```